# Why contains() method on ArrayList always returns false?

Tags: java, arraylist

My main problem is that the `contains()` method on my `ArrayList` returns always `false`, and I am not sure why.

I have created an `ArrayList<Position>` called `allValidPositions`, which contains many instances of my custom class called `Position`.

When I try to find a specific `Position` element in the `ArrayList`, it always returns `false`.

```
// The parameters represent X and Y coordinates
Position positionToCheck = new Position(0, 0);

if (allValidPositions.contains(positionToCheck) {
    System.out.println("Found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

It always prints `Not found` although I know that there is a Position that should be the same object (the fields and values in the objects are the same).

Comment: Did you remember to implement `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: `Position` probably doesn't override `equals`; so you get identity equality only. Not certain, you didn't post `Position`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`contains()` method is dependent on `equals()` method of the object contained within the list. In this case, make sure you have properly overridden `equals()` method in the `Position` class.

> How `contains()` works?

It picks up each object in your list and tries to equate it with the object that you passed by calling `equals()` method. Only if `equals()` is properly overridden you will be able to check logical equality. Otherwise, it will only return `true` if you pass the same reference.

Edit:

As per comment by @AselS, `contains()` is dependent on `indexOf()` which calls `equals()`.

Comment: Minor clarification: `contains()` utilizes the `indexOf()` (which has a helper method) that relies on `equals()`.

Comment: @AselS Thanks for that. Added the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it! With the correct override, it works perfectly now. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @NarendraPathai Ohh, and really thank you for your code edition. It really made my question more readable, and I have learned a lot from it. With your help, I'll post better questions in the future! Thanks for that as well!

Comment: @Zopy You are welcome, my friend. Make sure next time you also check if a similar question has been asked previously. Great that you are willing to learn and be a better SO citizen. All the best for your journey.